# How to handle shared data between samples and batches in Keras

Tags: keras

I'm using Keras for timeseries prediction and I want to create a model that is based on the self-attention mechanism that will not use any RNNs. For each sample we look at the last x timesteps of samples to predict the next sample.

In other words I want to feed the network (num_batches, num_samples, timesteps, features) and get (num_batches, predictions).

There is 1 problems with this.

1. There is a lot of unnecessary duplication of data where sample n has basically the same timesteps and features as sample n+1, only shifted 1 to the left.

How would you handle this assuming you dataset is very large?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with this, but if your issue is "I have too many replicated data" I think you can solve your problem devising a generator for your data, and then pass the generator as input for the Keras/TensorFlow fit function (according to TensorFlow APIs specification, it is stated that it supports generators as input).

If your question is related to the logic behind the model, I do not see the issue. It is like that you have a sliding window, for each window you predict one value, and then you move the window by a certain amount (in your case, one). Could you argue a little more about your concern?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll have to look into generators. I do need a batch to be more than one sample, but as long as I don't have to duplicate the whole dataset by the number of timesteps I should be fine.